# What's a good way for me to find a Katana, aside from Zed's Demise?

Tags: dead-island

So I'm level 41 and I just got to the Jungle, but I haven't seen a Katana since level 30. I found a Frail Katana on the beach of the first area at around level 30 inside of a metal chest. Since then, I have been checking shops and chests and enemies and what-have-you, yet I still have not seen any other Katanas. Aside from Zed's Demise (I'm not that far yet), is there any certain way to obtain a Katana?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Locations

- A side mission in the Jungle, given by Connor gives the Katana as a
  reward.
- A side mission to the prison leads to the legendary katana,
  Zed's Demise.
- Can be randomly dropped by zombies in the jungle.
- Different merchants in later levels of the game, can sometimes sell a
  Katana.*( Check merchants. I saw an Orange one for sale in the Jungle. Also, there's a scientist above the lab in the Jungle with a short chain of quests, just follow the winding path into the mountains till you hit a gate. He's right beside it locked in a building.)*

### A little FYI

Xian Mei can perform a special attack when her first blade skill is upgraded. The skill is activated when you aim at a zombies head or neck, then Xian presses the blade against the zombies neck, causing roughly 1000-2000 damage.

taken from [here](http://deadisland.wikia.com/wiki/Katana) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/622414-dead-island/answers?qid=292366).

Comment: I'm not far enough in the game to do the side mission, nor the mission for Zed's Demise. I have yet to see any zombies with a Katana in the Jungle. Which vendors can sometimes stock a Katana?

Comment: @Aceofgods I've added some more details to the answer above. The Katana will not spawn till later in the game. Players are saying they just find them among the loot if not from quests, however certainly available in the prison.